# Line thickness when sketching in Notes on iPad

Tags: ipad, notes.app

I recently got an iPad Pro with Apple pencil and smart keyboard. I like it a lot! I often need to create a quick sketch, and the Notes app seems perfect...

EXCEPT

I can't figure out how to change the line thickness for any of the tools (felt tip, marker, pencil) when I "added a sketch" to a note. This in contrast to "just drawing" in Notes - where the pen has pressure sensitivity, and tapping twice on the tool gives me a dialog with options to change color, thickness, .... It seems that inside the sketch app-in-app, "it is what it is". Also - it seems that the eraser behaves differently. In Notes, it deletes the entire pen stroke when you touch just part of it; in the app-in-app, it deletes only that part of the stroke that you touch. But the size of that eraser I can't fix.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to change the size / behavior of these tools when I "add a sketch", or is this just the basic way it is. It's very strange to me that these two ways of drawing inside the same app give different results.

Screen shots of the two situations attached.

In the sketch tool, I cannot edit the pens:

[image]

and in the notes app itself, I can:

[image]

This seems unusually un-Apple. Am I missing a trick, or is this an inconsistence in Apple's implementation?